# Storing collection of my class in database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, collections

I need to store in database collection of my class, like this:

```
class City {
    private String name;
    private List<String> points;
}
```

so my table should looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Cities {
    private Date date;
    private List<City> cities;
}
```

so how I can make it in Spring Web application?

Comment: "How can I make", what do you want to make? This is very unclear to me, and possibly too broad as well.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses hibernate to handle database data operations.

If you're using eclipse as an IDE, then you can install Hibernate Tools plugin as part of the [JBoss Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools). Hibernate Tools can reverse engineer your database schema into domain model (entity) classes.

---

*In order to install it:*

1. Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace... and search for JBoss Tools. In the list of results you should see "JBoss Tools 4.4.1.Final", click the install button next to it.
2. After that you need to select he features you want to install. Select only hibernate tools, then click confirm.
3. Accept the licence and click finish.
4. Restart eclipse

---

*In order to configure it:*

1. Open Hibernate perspective in eclipse
2. In the Hibernate Configurations view, click "Add Configuration..."
3. Select Annotations (jdk 1.5+)
4. For Hibernate version I prefer the latest one: 5.2
5. Browse the project you are working on
6. In the Database connection section click New..., select the type of database you are using, click next, add a new driver (you need to provide the JDBC driver's jar file), then input your database connection details (Database, URL, User name, Password). Click Test connection to check if the configuration was successful.
7. In the Configuration file section, click "Setup", then "Create new...".
8. Select the src folder of your project. The file name should remain hibernate.cfg.xml. Click next.
9. Click "Get values from connection", then select your previously created connection profile. In the database dialect, select the dialect of your database. Click Finish. Now you have the database configuration setup.

---

*In order to use it:*

1. In the menu, select Run > Hibernate Code Generation... > Hibernate Code Generation Configurations...
2. Create a new launch configuration.
3. In the launch configuration, select your previously created console configuration.
4. The output directory should be the src folder of your project.
5. Click Reverse engineer from JDBC Connection
6. Enter the name of the package where you want to generate your entity classes.
7. In the Exporters tab, select "Use Java 5 syntax" and "Generate EJB3 annotations", and select "Domain code (.java)" in the exporters section
8. Click Run, then check your package filled with entity classes.

---

I tried to reproduce your schema in a local database and ran the code generation.

This is what I ended up with:

**Point.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "point", schema = "public")
public class Point implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private City city;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Point() {
    }

    public Point(int id, City city, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city", nullable = false)
    public City getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "latitude", nullable = false, precision = 17, scale = 17)
    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Column(name = "longitude", nullable = false, precision = 17, scale = 17)
    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

**City.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city", schema = "public")
public class City implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String name;
    private Cities cities;
    private Set<Point> points = new HashSet<Point>(0);

    public City() {
    }

    public City(String name, Cities cities) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public City(String name, Cities cities, Set<Point> points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cities = cities;
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cities", nullable = false)
    public Cities getCities() {
        return this.cities;
    }

    public void setCities(Cities cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "city")
    public Set<Point> getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public void setPoints(Set<Point> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

**Cities.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities", schema = "public")
public class Cities implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>(0);

    public Cities() {
    }

    public Cities(int id, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Cities(int id, Date date, Set<City> cities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false, length = 13)
    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cities")
    public Set<City> getCities() {
        return this.cities;
    }

    public void setCities(Set<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

}
```

[This article should provide you further help.](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)